# Is a B-Tree of order 2 a full binary tree?

Tags: data-structures, tree, b-tree

When I made a search for the above question I got an answer `Yes`.

The definition for a full binary tree is as follows :

> A full binary tree (sometimes proper binary tree or 2-tree) is a tree in which every node other than the leaves has two children.

But the issue is that, this property might not be satisfied every time I construct a B-Tree of order 2.

For example :

> Insert 10,17,45 in a B-Tree of order 2

The structure that we get is

```
10
   17
      45
```

which is not a full binary tree.

So why is it said that a B-Tree of order 2 a full binary tree?

Comment: The 10, 17, 45 B-Tree you showed is not a B-Tree. B-Trees are self balanced trees, and that tree is not balanced.

Comment: Is my insertion faulty?

Comment: A correct insertion would have resulted in either (10,17),45 or 10,(17,45).

Comment: Is (10,17),45 of order 2? For a tree of order 2 every node must contain a single key if I am not wrong

Comment: A B-tree of order 2 can have one or 2 children per node. It would be an error to split a node before it was full, so you would expect your tree to have two nodes, not three, under any correct insertion implementation. Your tree is just a linked list, a degenerate case of no interest.

Comment: As far a I know, a tree with order m can have maximum of m-1 keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term 'order' is so poorly defined for B-trees as to be virtually useless... Everybody uses the term in a different manner.

Be that as it may, for any kind of B-tree the number of pointers in a node is determined by the number of keys in that node. If the number of keys is k then the number of pointers is k + 1, period. There's no choice regarding the number of pointers, as there might be in other kinds of trees. Either all pointers in a node are nil (root in a single-level 'tree', leaves) or all are valid, there's no in-between, no mixture.

Second, in order for the B-tree to function there needs to be a choice in the number of keys. This means that the smallest possible B-tree node is one that has either one or two keys (and hence two or three pointers). That's basically a (2,3)-tree and reportedly that's exactly how B-trees were invented - as a generalisation of (2,3)-trees.

Inserting the keys 10, 17 and 45 into an empty B-tree of the lowest possible order would go like this:

```
[]

[10]

[10 17]

   [17]
[10]  [45]
```

The final result does indeed happen to look like a balanced binary tree.

However, for the reasons indicated above there is no such thing as B-tree of order 2 in the sense that you seem to be using the term (at most two pointers per node). It would not be possible to maintain the B-tree invariants when inserting more than one key into such a degenerate B-tree.

Note: there are gazillions of B-tree variants that allow structural invariants of the classical B-tree to be violated temporarily or even permanently, mostly for attaining performance goals, to simplify maintenance, or to achieve special properties like lock-less concurrent operation. These would not be counted proper B-trees for the purpose of this discussion, even though they may have "B-tree" in their names.

Comment: Could you provide which are the reasons ```for the reasons indicated above there is no such thing as B-tree of order 2``` once again, please?

Comment: @Dragos: in a B-tree of order 2 (in the sense used by the OP, i.e. at most 2 pointers per node) there would be at most one key per node. Together with the fact that all nodes - except for the root of an empty tree - must have at least one key, we arrive at the fact that each node holds exactly one key. Hence you have a binary tree, not a B-tree.. A B-tree needs wiggle room in the number of keys per node in order to function, and the smallest node size that accomplishes this is a node that can hold either 1 or 2 keys (and hence either 2 or 3 pointers), i.e. order 3 by the OP's reckoning.

Comment: @DarthGizka not sure I got your reason. what you said seems like "a b-tree is a binary tree in that case". sound just like a 2-3-tree is a b-tree to me.

Answer (score 0):

According to `Fundamentals of Data Structure in C++ by Horowitz`, it mentioned that B tree of order 2 indeed must be a full tree. However, not any tree (any number of nodes) of order 2 (with 1 or 2 children) can be a B tree, only those having `2^k` nodes can form a B tree of order 2. On the other hand, it also mentioned that for B tree of `order > 2`, any number of nodes can form a B tree of `order > 2`. That is, B tree of order 2 is kind of a special case of B trees.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, let's take a look at the definition of a B-Tree of Order m:

1. Root has two children;
2. Every node should have no less than *ceil(m / 2)* children;
3. Leaf nodes should be placed at the same level.
4. (Something implicit given) B-Tree is also an **m-way Search Tree**

Note that, since a B-Tree is also an m-way Search Tree, every node which has *p* internal nodes should have no less than *p + 1* children. Therefore, as a B-tree of Order 2 requires every node have no less than 2 children and every node has no more than 2 children, a B-Tree of Order m is a full BST.